# zXing runtime error in Android

Tags: java, android, barcode, zxing, scanning

I'm trying to integrate zXing into my Android app.

I've created a new project from the "android project", set it as a library and insert the core.jar.

I've also have import it the project as a library into my app and insert the core.jar too, but when I launch my Intent, I keep getting this:

```
RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
```

I've read all the posts and tutorials, and I mean it, ALL of them, but I get no solution.

Can anyone help me please?

Kind regards and thanks for advance.

Comment: Include more of your logcat/stacktrace.

Comment: Be more specific with your question where are you facing problem while generating barcode or scanning barcode? Have to made entry for this in your manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing change the library project folder to the sdk location for this you have to make one folder which is extensions and then put zxing library file in to it and then import that all library in to you project explorer and then give the reference of library again and you can also follow this below site .....

http://www.androidaz.com/development/zxing-qr-reader-direct-integration